# Comparing JSON string element with JavaScript string

Tags: javascript, json, database

I have came across an odd problem with getting JSON data like the following.

```
[
   {
      "type":"ripe",
      "red":137,
      "green":68,
      "blue":40,
      "strftime(\"%H:%M:%S\", time)":"18:46:37"
   },
]
```

I was not able to compare this data by type using JavaScript, they both successfully went through my if statement for some odd reason. The total count for both variables is equal to 2.

```
            let counterLoop = function() {
                for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                    let fruitType = JSON.stringify(data[i].type);
                    sortFruit(fruitType.toLowerCase());
                }
            }
            let sortFruit = function(fruitType) {
                if (fruitType.localeCompare('ripe') === 0){} {
                    totalRipeFruit++;
                    $("#totalRipeFruit").text(totalRipeFruit);
                }
                if (fruitType.localeCompare('unripe') === 0){} {
                    totalUnripeFruit++;
                    $("#totalUnripeFruit").text(totalUnripeFruit);
                }
            }
```

Any idea why this could be the case?

Thank you very much!

Comment: `if (fruitType.localeCompare('ripe') === 0){} {` <= what is this syntax?

Comment: Both of your if statements are being given an empty `{}` block, so they do nothing.  Then they are followed by a block that is not dependent upon the if statement, that always happen.  Seems like a typo, but want to make sure you're not thinking this should work another way, and does not

Comment: @Taplar that sounds like an answer, especially if you can get a working snippet to go with it.

Comment: @GarrettMotzner If the issue is a typo, then it is not an answer.  If it is a typo, the question is closable as being a typo question, as it holds little value for future readers.

Comment: @Taplar, can't believe I was scratching my head over this for this long.. but any idea why it's not displaying any sort of number after this fix?

Comment: @Taplar Oh, didn't see that there was a typo flag. It's kinda hidden. Thanks for clueing me in :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two problems here; First of all there is no need for the `JSON.stringify`on the type, just leave it out as it will return the string containing useless quotes.
Secondly, your if statements are messed up: You have a second pair of brackets behind each one, so simply change

```
        if (fruitType.localeCompare('ripe') === 0){} {
            totalRipeFruit++;
            $("#totalRipeFruit").text(totalRipeFruit);
        }
        if (fruitType.localeCompare('raw') === 0){} {
            totalRawFruit++;
            $("#totalRawFruit").text(totalRawFruit);
        }
```

To:

```
if (fruitType.localeCompare('ripe') === 0) {
    totalRipeFruit++;
}
if (fruitType.localeCompare('raw') === 0) {
    totalRawFruit++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it was both issues that were causing me this problem...